# JS Shorthand return first value which is not undefined

Tags: javascript

I want to use this shorthand, because it check and return `b` if its value is `true`. This is good, because if b is a function i dont have to call it twice.

```
const a = b || c
```

But it doesn't work if i want to return b where `b = 0` or `b = ""`
So i need to use this code, but there i need to call b twice.

```
const a = (b != null) ? b : c
```

So, is there a shorthand like the first code which also return b if it is `0` or `""`?

Comment: can `b` have other values than empty string or zero?

Comment: Please list all values of `b` for which `c` should be returned.

Comment: `b` can be any string or number
`c` will return if `b = undefined` or `b = null`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[It is making it's way to the ECMA script specification](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing), where we have a null coalescing operator. It is already supported by TypeScript :)

```
const a = b ?? c;
```

So right now, if you're using a TypeScript compiler, you can use the operator. However, if you're using just vanilla JS then you will need to implement a null/undefined check manually, unfortunately, due to a general lack of cross-browser support.

At the time of writing, only [Chrome and Firefox supports the `??` operator](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing). You can also refer to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) on how it can be used.

You can test here if your browser supports it:

```js
const payload = {
  foo: 0,
  foz: 1,
  bar: '',
  baz: 'Lorem ipsum',
};

console.log(payload.foo ?? 999);  // 0
console.log(payload.foz ?? 999);  // 1
console.log(payload.bar ?? 'Fallback text');  // <empty string>
console.log(payload.baz ?? 'Fallback text');  // Lorem ipsum
console.log(payload.x ?? 'Oh no!'); // Oh no!

console.log(payload.foo || 999);  // 999
console.log(payload.foz || 999);  // 1
console.log(payload.bar || 'Fallback text');  // Fallback text
console.log(payload.baz || 'Fallback text');  // Lorem ipsum
console.log(payload.x || 'Oh no!');  // Oh no!
```